# Como criar um índice único baseado em duas colunas?

Tags: sql-server, índices, constraint

Tenho uma tabela com estas colunas:

```
ip
nome
email
```

Quero que `ip` e o `email` sejam um par único. Um mesmo valor de `ip` pode conter vários registros e um mesmo `email` também pode. Porém o mesmo `ip` e mesmo `email` deve ser único.

Tal que, isto seria possível:

```
  - ip              nome              email
1 - 187.89.98.4     João              joao@gmail.com  // ip repetido com registro 2
2 - 187.89.98.4     Maria             maria@gmail.com // ip repetido com registro 1; email repetido com registro 3
3 - 197.19.1.47     Vinicius          maria@gmail.com // e-mail repetido com registro 2
```

Porém isto não:

```
  - ip              nome              email
1 - 187.89.98.4     João              joao@gmail.com // mesmo ip com mesmo e-mail com registro 2
2 - 187.89.98.4     Maria             joao@gmail.com // mesmo ip com mesmo e-mail com registro 1
```

pois não quero que o par `ip` e `email` se repita.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IpEmail ON tabela (ip ASC, email ASC)
```

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Espero que tenha um outra coluna que seja a primária, estes dados podem variar e não são bons candidatos a chave primária. Se quiser insistir:

```
ALTER TABLE tabela ADD CONSTRAINT IpEmail PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ip, email);
```

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-primary-keys?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Create/NewIndex.sql).

Comment: Quais são bons candidatos a chave primária? Em exemplos rasos, não se prendendo ao contexto de minha pergunta.

Comment: Acho que isto é outra pergunta e capaz de eu já ter respondido: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A101+chave+prim%C3%A1ria